# autoprint table from website

Tags: java, html

I wish to autoprint every day certain content from the site http://www.smhi.se/weatherSMHI2/extremer/extremerLandsdel_sv.htm#
The site is autogenerated at certain times but I do not know how. Is it possible for someone to give me a hint on how I can extract the data from the table every day and print it, with a script? I understand the task is not easy because the site is in Swedish, but the web source code is for everyone with website programming skill to understand. Also it is hard to understand immidiately what I need, because English is not my native language, so you are free to ask me further questions to pinpoint the task at hand.

Comment: What do you mean by autoprinting? Do you want to have a hard copy of this page in a day by day basis? Or just having this simple data stored somewhere (like DB or saved html page) will be enough?

Comment: I wish to have a hard copy on the printer, if possible. If I could save the html page would be nice too. As you can see there are several choices, like max/min temp, wind, precipitation etc. so I would like to reach those data/page and print/save aswell.

Comment: I thought maybe I could extract the div id sections, but with my programming skills I can do it by Reading the original html and Writing to a new html specifically with the lowtemp, hightemp etc sections. Any other way to do it more easy?

Comment: I have made the script now in VBS, Reading line by line and extracting the different tables Writing to different htm-files. Not so neat but that is how far my skill stretched. If you are interested I could post the code here somehow?